# How do I append a string to a URL

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, url

I am working on an Angular app and having a bit of a problem.
I am trying to test my API by appending a string into a URL.
It works fine when I hardcode the string into the URL but when I append it won't work.

this is a function that will get the string that I want to append.

```
 getString(str: string){
    this.strAppend = str
  }
```

this is the URL,

`url: string =` http://localhost:3000/document/id/${this.strAppend}/transaction?from=1610742245&to=1623439932

notice how I use this.strAppend. Well, this is not working. Is this even the right approach?

Comment: this.strAppend = str, this line is not appending a value, it's assigning a value

Comment: @Nonik shouldn't my URL work if after assigning i use it in URL

Comment: not when value is re-assigned. Ryan below provided a solution for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Template Literals to solve your problem.

```
var base = 'url'

getString(strToAdd: string) {
  return `${base}/${strToAdd}`;
}

var newStr = getString('test');
```

Comment: And notice that the string literals are enclosed by the single quote, while the template literal returned is enclosed in the backward tick, not the single quote mark.

Answer (score 0):

First declare the variable in string
for time being refer this

```
  $scope.str1 = 'This is ';
        $scope.str2 = 'Sticked Toghether';
        $scope.res = '';
        $scope.join = function() {
            $scope.res = $scope.str1 + $scope.str2;
        };
```